# Manipulating AD groups with powershell - prompt for yes or no for each object in selection?

Tags: powershell

Here's what I have so far:

```
$UserFrom = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter username of person to pull group memberships from'
$UserTo = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter username of person to apply these groups to'
$Groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserFrom | Where-Object {$_.name -ne "Domain Users"}
Write-Host 'Copying over the groups...'
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserTo -MemberOf $Groups
Write-Host 'Completed!'
```

This works perfectly, what I'd like to do is instead of copying all the groups over, receive a prompt for each one. Do you want to copy this one? (Y/N). Then the next, and the next, until it has gone through them all.

If anyone can help me with this I would be very grateful. If it is giving me the code I need that is amazing but even if you can just tell what I need to read about that would be very helpful. I am a beginner.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a confirm requirement like so:

```
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserTo -MemberOf $Groups -Confirm:$true
```

For confirmation for each group, you can do a loop:

```
Foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
  Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserTo -MemberOf $Group -Confirm:$true
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. That works but that prompts for confirmation for all the groups at once, whereas i want it to ask "confirm group [X Name]? (Y/N)" and then "confirm group [Y Name]? (Y/N)" and so on, a prompt for each group where Y adds the group membership and N moves onto the next one. Is this possible?

Comment: I added another code block that may do what you need.